# Is it ok to actually use multipliers on anchors?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

Is it ok to use multipliers on anchors and on centers ?
For me, at least for start this made no sense at all, but then I dig in a bit and I saw that this actually works.

So let me get this strait.
Tell me if I'm wrong please.

1) Leading with multiplier of 1 = Trailing ? I've seen that leading with multiplier of 0.1, means 10% inside (based on width).

2) Center with multiplier of 2 = Trailing ? By the assumption that center means trailing / 2 or leading * 0.5 ?

As far as I learned, the multiplier actually multiplies by the width / height based on the axis.

This means that the following constraints are equivalent ?

**C1.axis = C2.axis * M + C <=> C1.axis = C2.axis + axisLength * M + C ?**

So the multiplier just adds that multiple of the width or height ?

UPDATE:

So to clear things out with info from the accepted answer.

```
CenterX_or_Y = Width_or_Height / 2
Trailing - Leading = Width  (in therms of size)
Bottom   - Top     = Height (in therms of size)
```

When you actually use multipliers on Leading/Trailing/Top/Bottom you are actually using the multipliers on the above sizes (width or height).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Multipliers on sizes is pretty straight-forward... I want my subview to be 80% of of the width of its superview, so I just set Equal widths with a Multiplier of `0.8`

However, it can get confusing when using Multipliers on Leading / Trailing / Center / etc.

From Apple's [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW1):

[image]

So, for example, let's say:

```
Red Leading is set to Blue Trailing, Constant 8, Multiplier 1
Blue Leading is at 0, and width is 100

Red's Leading will be (1.0 x 100) + 8 = 108
```

To be clear, though, Blue's Trailing is not the same as its Width.

Suppose Blue's Leading is at `50`? If its Width is 100, its Trailing will be 150, so:

```
Red's Leading will be (1.0 x 150) + 8 = 158
```

Now, put Blue's Leading back to `0` but let's change the Multiplier to 0.75

```
Red's Leading will be (0.75 x 100) + 8 = 83
```

and, if Blue's Leading is 50, then Blue's Trailing is 150:

```
Red's Leading will be (0.75 x 150) + 8 = 120.5
```

Just refer back to the formula to keep things straight:

```
item1.attribute = multiplier * item2.attribute + constant
```

---

Here's a visual example to clarify. All labels are `100x40`, and each Green label is constrained Green.Leading = Blue.Trailing + Constant: 8

[image]

For Set #1, the Multiplier is `1.0` - for sets #2, #3 and #4, the Multiplier is `0.5`.

Set 1, Blue's Leading is `0`, and Green's Multiplier is `1` ... This is what one normally sees, and it is obvious - Green is 8-pts from Blue's Trailing, which is (Blue.Leading + Blue.Width), or

```
1.0 * (0 + 100) = 100
100 + 8 = 108
```

Set 2, Blue's Leading is still `0`, but Green's Multiplier is `0.5` ... so Green is 8-pts from Blue's Trailing, which is (Blue.Leading + Blue.Width), * 0.5, or

```
0.5 * (0 + 100) = 50
50 + 8 = 58
```

Set 3, Blue's Leading is now `80`, Green's Multiplier is still `0.5` ... so Green is 8-pts from Blue's Trailing, which is (Blue.Leading + Blue.Width), * 0.5, or

```
0.5 * (80 + 100) = 90
90 + 8 = 98
```

Set 4 looks odd. Blue's Leading is now `200`, Green's Multiplier is still `0.5` ... so Green is 8-pts from Blue's Trailing, which is (Blue.Leading + Blue.Width), * 0.5, or

```
0.5 * (200 + 100) = 150
150 + 8 = 158
```

As we see, in Set #4 Green ends up being Left of Blue, which is correct, but not all that intuitive.

Comment: Yes. but that exact same formula causes problems. People can't understand multiplier * leading/trailing/top/bottom... people can only easily understand multiplier * size... which in fact is what it is. Apple documentation just sux. So my assumption was correct I see. This is the actual formular used, where axis is more like position.
C1.axis = C2.axis * M + C <=> C1.axis = C2.axis + axisLength * M + C ?

Comment: PS: when I compared those anchors, I actually ment in therms of size...
So Trailing - Leading = Width, Bottom - Top = Height and so on.

Comment: @AlinLipan - I added some visual examples to (hopefully) make sure the explanation is clear.

Comment: Thank you for the visual, it actually is different then what I expected. The multiplier has nothing to do with the width alone...  it actually depends on the whole leading + width thingy.